# Sentence relativized to $V_{\omega_1}$

Tags: logic, set-theory

Find a sentence $\psi$ such that $\psi^{V_{\omega_1}}$ holds but for every $\alpha < \omega_1, \psi^{V_{\alpha}}$ fails.

I can't find such a sentence. Also, since $\alpha < \omega_1$, shouldn't a sentence which is relativized to $V_{\alpha}$ hold if it holds relativized to $V_{\omega_1}$ (since $V_{\alpha} \subset V_{\omega_1}$)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following sentence: every countable well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal. This holds in $V_{\omega_1}$ as it contains every countable ordinal. However, it does not hold over any $V_\alpha$ for countable $\alpha>\omega$. In fact, we can find a well-ordered relation $E\in V_{\omega+1}$ over $\omega$ which is isomorphic to $\alpha$: for each $\alpha$, there is a relation $E\subseteq\omega\times\omega$ such that $(\omega, E)\cong (\alpha,\in)$. Since $E\subseteq V_\omega$, $E\in V_{\omega+1}$.

(*Note: we can exclude the case $\alpha\le \omega$ by adding the axiom of infinity, as Asaf pointed out.*)

Your conjecture on absoluteness between $V_\alpha$ and $V_{\omega_1}$ is simply false. Just a subset relation does not affect to absoluteness in general. However, you can show that if $\phi$ is a $\Pi_1$ sentence (that is, every unbounded quantifiers of $\phi$ is universal) and $\phi^{V_{\omega_1}}$ holds then $\phi^{V_{\alpha}}$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$.

Comment: You need to also require that Infinity holds, otherwise $V_\omega$ satisfies that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are right. I forgot to mention it.